# Django model CreateView does not render form fields in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to setup a class based 'CreateView' for a model in my django site, but when the create html page renders, the model fields are not rendered. Only the submit button shows up on the web page. However, when debugging, I overrided the 'form_invalid' method in the class view, and the form object had the required HTML for all fields stored in the object. If I take this HTML and manually add it to the HTML of the create page in the browser I can fill out the fields and post the data to the database.

At this point I have not found an obvious answer as to why the form fields are not rendered so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

environment used: python 3.7.3, django 2.2.3

---

**Solution:**

This issue was fixed by changing the form name in the view context data.

In views.py:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateAlertView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["alert_form"]=context["form"]
        return context
```

Or...
In the HTML template change 'alert_form' to 'form' to match the default context.

---

models.py:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    RAIN = 'Rain'
    SNOW = 'Snow'
    COLD = 'Cold'
    HEAT = 'Heat'
    WEATHER_CHOICES = [
        (RAIN, 'Rain'),
        (SNOW, 'Snow'),
        (COLD, 'Cold'),
        (HEAT, 'Heat'),
    ]

    DAILY = 'Daily'
    WEEKLY = 'Weekly'
    INTERVAL_CHOICES = [
        (DAILY, 'Daily'),
        (WEEKLY, 'Weekly'),
    ]

    weather_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=WEATHER_CHOICES, default=RAIN)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default=DAILY)
    search_length = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
class CreateAlertView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/alert_form.html'
    #model = Alert
    form_class = AlertModelForm
    success_url = 'users/profile/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        print('validation')
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form) # check form HTML here
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

forms.py:

```
class AlertModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        exclude = ['user']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('alert/create/', CreateAlertView.as_view(), name='alert'),
]
```

html template:

```
<h1>create an alert</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ alert_form.as_p }}
    {{ alert_form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ field.errors }}
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Create page as rendered:

[image: Create page as rendered]

Create page with manually modified HTML:
[image: Create page with manually modified HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context name for the form set by the CreateView (FormMixin) is "form", your template is referencing "alert_form"

[Here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_context_data) is a helpful website for seeing all options available in the class based views

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link, that is very helpful information. One follow-up question: I thought the form definition was handled by the ``` form_class = AlertModelForm ``` setting in the create view. But I should also set the context name for the form in get_context_data()?

Comment: @LucLapenta unfortunately the `FormMixin` does not give a nice way to change the name of the form in the context. You could override the `get_context_data` method and change the name of the form in the context dict